# Navbar List Items Not Showing in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: list, internet-explorer-6, navbar

I have a bit of a problem with a navbar not displaying correctly in IE6. http://classicpartsltd.com/ - this is the page, and if you hover over a nav item such as 'Goggles' in IE6 you will see that some of the list items are showing up, but that they will in IE7 and IE8... Does anyone know why this would be the case?

Many thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 1):

No worries, it was a combination of too great a width and float being applied where undesired.